# SQL Server sample of each type of record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table full of records for various semesters, and I want a query to select the top 5 rows from each semester.

I'd like one resultset sorted by a key field (serial) and one resultset with random sorts within each semester.

The table looks like this:

- serial int
- semester char(4)
- grade int

Table data:

```
Semester|Serial|NewSerial
SP10    |1     |1001
SP10    |2     |1002
SP10    |3     |1003
SP10    |4     |1004
SP10    |5     |1005
SP10    |6     |1006
SP10    |7     |1007
SP10    |8     |1008
SP10    |9     |1009
SP10    |10    |1010
FA10    |1     |2001
FA10    |2     |2002
FA10    |3     |2003
FA10    |4     |2004
FA10    |5     |2005
FA10    |6     |2006
FA10    |7     |2007
FA10    |8     |2008
FA10    |9     |2009
FA10    |10    |2010
FA09    |1     |3001
FA09    |2     |3002
FA09    |3     |3003
FA09    |4     |3004
FA09    |5     |3005
FA09    |6     |3006
FA09    |7     |3007
FA09    |8     |3008
FA09    |9     |3009
FA09    |10    |3010
```

Result 1: ordered by serial, top 5

```
Semester|Serial|NewSerial
SP10    |1     |1001
SP10    |2     |1002
SP10    |3     |1003
SP10    |4     |1004
SP10    |5     |1005
FA10    |1     |2001
FA10    |2     |2002
FA10    |3     |2003
FA10    |4     |2004
FA10    |5     |2005
FA09    |1     |3001
FA09    |2     |3002
FA09    |3     |3003
FA09    |4     |3004
FA09    |5     |3005
```

Result 2: order by random within semester (sampling)

```
Semester|Serial|NewSerial
SP10    |3     |1003
SP10    |1     |1001
SP10    |5     |1005
SP10    |2     |1002
SP10    |4     |1004
FA10    |2     |2002
FA10    |1     |2001
FA10    |4     |2004
FA10    |3     |2003
FA10    |5     |2005
FA09    |3     |3003
FA09    |1     |3001
FA09    |2     |3002
FA09    |5     |3005
FA09    |4     |3004
```

Comment: You didn't provide data examples, are we to assume higher grade values mean top?  And what version of SQL Server?  What have you tried?

Comment: where is grade column in your test data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

these should do it:

```
WITH [query_semester] AS (
    SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY semester
    ORDER BY serial),
    serial, semester, grade
    FROM SemesterTable)
SELECT serial, semester, grade
FROM [query_semester] WHERE [RN] <= 5;
```

and the random one:

```
WITH [query_semester] AS (
    SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY semester
    ORDER BY NEWID()),
    serial, semester, grade
    FROM SemesterTable)
SELECT serial, semester, grade
FROM [query_semester] WHERE [RN] <= 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Show us some sample data, and expected results.

You will need to SELECT TOP 5
You will also need to GROUP BY the semester type (if that is a date so be it).

Instead of TOP 5 use HAVING count...

Comment: TOP 5 will only return records (assuming there are 5+), regardless of GROUP BY

Comment: OMG Ponies so use having COUNT

Answer (score 0):

No idea what criteria you are using to make up the new serial, but if it just needs to be serially incrementing by semester (in the thousand position), then

```
select semester, serial,
    newserial = (DENSE_RANK() over (order by semester) * 1000) + rn
from
(   select *, rn=ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by semester order by serial)
    from tbl
) x
where rn <= 5
order by semester
```

For the order by serial.  Swap `order by serial` for `order by newid()` to get the random sampling.

Notes:

1. SQL Server 2005+ at compatibility level 90+
2. The formula for newserial works fine because each semester can only have 5 items so there won't be clashing issues

#### EDIT

It seems counter-intuitive in the question, but if newserial is just a regular field (it wasn't listed), then the select part becomes simply

```
select semester, serial, newserial
```

Comment: NewSerial is actually a field unto itself, so it doesn't ened operations.

Comment: @Caveatrob Did you just mark down an answer that attempted to answer your question?